# Pick a random line from a file in a batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, generator

I'm trying to make a `Character_Picker.bat` that echo a randomly picked string from a `characters.txt` a long text file. I have no idea how to do a random pick.

Characters.txt:

```
Disco Jockey Acid Pol
Double Agent Acid Pol
Muaythai Acid Pol
Paramedic Acid Pol
WWII Acid Pol
WWII Acid Pol
PB Quinn Chou
Secret Agent Chou
Rider Chou
General Chou
Grim Reaper Chou
Psycho Nurse Chou
Highschool Chou
Invasion Chou
Army Agent Chou
Kung Fu Chou
Rogue Agent Chou
Sweet Heart Chou
.
.
.
.333 strings more
```

My Batch Code:

```
@echo off
color a
cd Desktop
start "characters.txt"  ==> this is the thing where I stuck
set /a string=%random% %% 334
echo %string%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
@echo off
set /a rand=%random% %% 334
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n .* "d:\characters.txt"') do (
if "%%i"=="%rand%" echo %%j
)
```

We set `rand` and limit the random numbers to 334.
We then read the file and findstr the line number, if that number matches the random string, print the string.

just so you understand the `delims=:` portion. `findstr /n .* "d:\characters.txt"` will print the line number, then a colon and the actual line. Something like:

```
1:Disco Jockey Acid Pol
2:Double Agent Acid Pol
3:Muaythai Acid Pol
4:Paramedic Acid Pol
5:WWII Acid Pol
....
```

`delims=:` uses the `:` as delimiter and we assign line number to `%%i` and the actual line text to `%%j` Hence matching `%%i` with `%rand%` and then printing `%%j`

for doing multiple random runs, add a `for /l` loop, this example will do 4 random lines:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do call :run
goto :EOF
:run
set /a rand=%random% %%334
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n .* "d:\characters.txt"') do (
    if "%%i"=="%rand%" echo %%j
)
```

or to prompt you each time how many randoms you'd like:

```
@echo off
set /p num=How many?
for /l %%a in (1,1,%num%) do call :run
goto :EOF
:run
set /a rand=%random% %%334
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n .* "d:\characters.txt"') do (
    if "%%i"=="%rand%" echo %%j
)
```

Comment: not working :-(
Error
<code>
C:\Users\alea\Documents>∩╗┐@echo off
'∩╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\alea\Documents>set /a rand=24832 % 334

C:\Users\alea\Documents>for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %i in ('findstr /n .* "d:\characters.txt"'
) do (if "%i" == "116" echo %j )
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
</code>

Comment: did you copy it and paste to your batch file exactly as I posted it? or did you paste it to cmd.exe?

Comment: why? just copy everything as is and paste into a file and name it `char_picker.cmd` then run it from `cmd.exe` and see the result. And obviously set your path to `characters.txt`

Comment: the '@echo off' is not working. it displays '∩╗┐@echo off'

Comment: Because you have special characters hidden somewhere. Clear the line and retype it. Make sure it is pure batch as per my previous comment.

Comment: i found it! It was in Encoded in UTF-8  convert to ANSI. And then add `cd C:\Windows\System32' next to `@echo off` bec of the `findstr' is not a external command

Comment: @JhonreyDaffon, `findstr` is indeed an external command, but it should usually be found without changing to the system directory, because this should be part of the `PATH` environment variable anyway, unless you messed around with it...

Comment: @Gerhard great job you did. How can is random pick more than 1 line at once? Ability to choose 1,2,3,4 lines  or how many i need.

Comment: @IonutBejinariu simply add a `for /l` loop, open `cmd` and run `for /?` for all the details, I have included two examples bottom of the answer.

Comment: @Gerhard great job again, can be done with nested loops also? as I have some other nested loops before and after that, and I need to integrate this

Comment: @Gerhard also adding an index for those `%%334` can be possible? I mean pick unique random from those 334 and only after unique picking start again to pick. this will be amazing feature.

Comment: Yes @IonutBejinariu, it can be done with nested loops. You can index the random values using either an array like variable system or by temporarily writing the values to a temp file and check each one each time.

Comment: @Gerhard I tried with nested loops, but did'n worked... I did something wrong for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would at first determine the number of lines in the text file, then determine a random number in that range, and then extract exactly this line, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F %%C in ('^< "characters.txt" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
set /A "NUMBER=%RANDOM%%%%COUNT%"
if %NUMBER% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%NUMBER%") else (set "SKIP=")
for /F usebackq^ %SKIP:skip=skip^%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("characters.txt") do (
    echo(%%L
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
```

If the target line is empty, then the next non-empty one would be returned by this code.
This approach supports text files with not more than 32768 lines.